# Bootstrap 4 Dropdown Menu not working?

Tags: javascript, css, html, bootstrap-4

I copied the official Bootstrap 4 example for dropdown menus but it is not working, that is nothing is dropped down.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: working for me https://jsbin.com/bumeqopuwu/edit?html,output .. Have you included the lib properly?

Comment: yes i included bootstrap.css, jquery.js, and bootstrap.js

Comment: What bootstrap 4 version are you including (bootstrap.js, css)?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Edit: In case anyone else is having this problem, I believe the solution for OP was that he had not imported `popper.js`.

Check that jQuery and all the relevant Bootstrap components are there. Also check the console and make sure there are no errors.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<-- Always remember to call the above files first before calling the bootstrap.min.js file -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using the Bootstrap 4 nuget package, I was referencing `Scripts/popper.js` instead of `Scripts/umd/poopper.js`. The former has an `export` statement on the last line that was creating an error in Chrome.

Comment: @moidol  I am also facing the same issue but only at the first time click. I have angular 10 project and the angular.json script tag looks like
`"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]`

Comment: Well done.  I think the order of those CDNs was the important part.

Answer (score 17):

try to add these lines at the end of the file

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If this is my issue, do you think it is webpack causing the problem?  [This](https://github.com/justin-capalbo/Grocerist.Net/tree/feature/navStyle/Grocerist.Web) is the branch where I'm having the same issue.  It seems that when I run the site in VS, the bootstrap jquery functionality is not enabled even if the styles are.

Answer (score 10):

Add this code to  your jquery

```
  $('.dropdown').click(function(){

       $('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('show');

   });
```

Comment: There's a lot of things wrong with this approach. you're toggling the "show" class on ALL dropdowns anytime ANY drop down is clicked. And you're click event is bound to the wrong element, it should be on `.dropdown-toggle`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming Bootstrap and Popper libraries were installed using Nuget package manager, for a web application using Visual Studio, in the Master page file (Site.Master), right below where body tag begins, include the reference to popper.min.js by typing:

```
<script src="Scripts/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

Here is an image to better display the location:

[image]

Notice the reference of the popper library to be added should be the one inside **umd** folder and not the one outside on Scripts folder.

This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Via JavaScript
Call the dropdowns via JavaScript:

Paste this is code after **bootstrap.min.js**

`$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();`

Also, make sure you include **popper.min.js** before **bootstrap.min.js**

Dropdowns are positioned thanks to Popper.js (except when they are contained in a navbar).

Comment: thanks for this answer, this worked for me in the end - I had to manually start calling $.dropdown()

Answer (score 3):

include them with this order
this will work
i dont know why :D

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper -->
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap js -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an issue with `popper.js` file. What I found at the official site was that bundle files include popper in itself but not jquery. I managed to fix it by adding link to these files:

`bootstrap.bundle.js`
`bootstrap.bundle.min.js`

I removed `popper.js` however since it comes within the bundle file.

Comment: You have to call these files before your bootstrap.js called.

Comment: You solved my problem after much googling. I was missing popper.js

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to include the Bootstrap CSS either via the [Bootstrap CDN](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css) 
or download it and link it locally

Comment: bootstrap.css is included, other components working.

Answer (score 1):

I used NuGet to install BootStrap 4.  I was also having issues with it not displaying the Dropdown on click.  It kept throwing an error in jquery base on what the Chrome console was telling me.

I originally had the following

```
<%-- CSS --%>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap.css" />

 <%-- JS --%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

But I changed it to use the bundled version instead and it started to work

```
<%-- CSS --%>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap.css" />

<%-- JS --%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this line of code to the end of the body tag

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer is to replace this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="your_directory/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

for this other:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="your_directory/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This is my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxSvI.png)

I just downloaded jquery's latest version from their official [website](https://jquery.com/download/) and then added it as a js file in my project folder and then to my HTML file. After that it was working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to enqueue the script bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js. I had the same problem with bootstrap 4.5.3 and the menu worked when I enqueued one of the above scripts. It can be either.

Answer (score -4):

It needs to be `/bootstrap.js`, **not** `/bootstrap.min.js`.

Comment: What if OP has downloaded minified version of bootstrap?