# Bootstrap dropdown menu does not work with FastApi

Tags: python, html, bootstrap-4, fastapi

I create a simple bootstrap dropdown example. I am using it with FastAPi. The content of the menu appears empty. What is wrong here? I am running the code on VS code. I tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46026899/bootstrap-4-dropdown-menu-not-working) but it does not work.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Sidebar  -->
    <nav id="sidebar">
        <div id="dismiss">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
        </div>
    
        <div class="sidebar-header">
            <h3>FastAPI</h3>
        </div>
    
        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#"class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton1"  data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Content</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdownMenuButton1">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/X/A" class="dropdown-item">A</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/X/B"class="dropdown-item">B</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/X/C">C</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: you could use `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` if you have these elements in HTML. Second you can use `DevTools` to change some values in CSS and HTML until it will work. As for me all problem is `Bootstrap` and/or `CSS`  and it has nothing to do with Python and FastAPI.

Comment: I don't see any CSS files in this HTML - so in my browser it looks like white page without styles. Maybe you load different HTML - with CSS but without dropdown menu.