# Dropdown Menu Won't Drop Down

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, navigation

Below is the relevant HTML for my _Layout.cshtml page. My issue is that when you click the dropdown menu, Supporting Tables, nothing happens - nothing drops down. I have even tried many other examples after searching Google, but none worked. Finally, one stylesheet link from an online how-to worked, but it changed the styles of my page, so am looking for a solution that won't do that.

Would appreciate it if someone could take a look and see what I might have wrong/be missing. I think it must be a script src or stylesheet link, but I do not know which one I would need to add or replace. Very new to this, so am sorry for my ignorance. Thank you!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - EmergencyContactsWeb</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootswatch_darkly.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark bg-dark box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">PHECWeb</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-page="/InfoSites/Index">Site Information</a>
                        </li>
                        <!--Dropdown Below-->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Supporting Tables</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" asp-area="" asp-page="/MDSpecialties/Index">MD Specialities</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" asp-area="" asp-page="/ResCategories/Index">Residence Categories</a>
                                    </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">...
```

Comment: I do not see any error messages. Can you please tell me where I should look EXACTLY? Perhaps I am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this on another stackoverflow post (I had searched here prior to posting the question, but must have used other search terms. I found this on Google.)

I needed to include these script srcs under my link rels and in this order:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The link to the original solution is here:
[Bootstrap 4 Dropdown Menu not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46026899/bootstrap-4-dropdown-menu-not-working)

Hope that can help others! I had no idea there was a particular order.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Bootstrap but cdn of bootstrap CSS is not included in your head tag. The only thing you have to do is to add this to your head tag :

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```

Comment: I added as you suggested. It changed the theme from all dark to light background with black menu, but dropdown menu will still not work.

Comment: Also, wouldn't this include all I needed from Boostrap?

<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: The theme is not a major issue. It can be changed accordingly. Actually, when I run this code on my local the bootstrap CSS was not working and hence its javascript was also not working when I added bootstrap CSS, Dropdown started working fine. If it's still not working on your local, try changing the bootstrap version and running again. I hope it would work. Thank you!:)